# I am unable to center my <script> in my html

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net, razor

Here is the code:

```html
<div class="jumbotron text-center">
  <h1>Aela and Heimskr</h1>
  <p class="lead">October 20, 2020 &bull; Whiterun, Skyrim</p>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td id="days"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <br/>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function countdown() {
      var now = new Date();
      var weddingDate = new Date(2020, 10, 20);

      var currentDate = now.getTime();
      var weddingDate = weddingDate.getTime();

      var remainingTime = weddingDate - currentDate;

      var s = Math.floor(remainingTime / 1000);
      var m = Math.floor(s / 60);
      var h = Math.floor(m / 60);
      var d = Math.floor(h / 24);

      document.getElementById("days").innerText = d + " Days to go!";
    }

    countdown();
  </script>
  <p><a href="../Rsvp/Create" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">RSVP &raquo;</a></p>
</div>
```

The bootstrap class 'text-center' in the first div centers all the other text but the script...

I have tried putting the script in a div and using the style tag to set widths, center text, center object, marigns, etc. and bootstrap classes to center it but nothing is working.

Does it have to do with the getElementById.innerText? I've only recently picked back up coding so I apologize if this seems a bit "newbie"

Thanks - let me know if you need anything for clarification

Answer (score 0):

Try giving the script a class. Like this:

````html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <div class="jumbotron text-center">
        <h1>Aela and Heimskr</h1>
        <p class="lead">October 20, 2020 &bull; Whiterun, Skyrim</p>
        <table class="w-100">
            <tr>
                <td class="text-center" id="days"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <br/>
        <script type="text/javascript" class="your_class">
            function countdown() {
                var now = new Date();
                var weddingDate = new Date(2020, 10, 20);

                var currentDate = now.getTime();
                var weddingDate = weddingDate.getTime();

                var remainingTime = weddingDate - currentDate;

                var s = Math.floor(remainingTime / 1000);
                var m = Math.floor(s / 60);
                var h = Math.floor(m / 60);
                var d = Math.floor(h / 24);

                document.getElementById("days").innerText = d + " Days to go!";
            }

            countdown();
        </script>
        <p><a href="../Rsvp/Create" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">RSVP &raquo;</a></p>
    </div>``` I don't know if it will work right because i never tried using the "class" element property in a script tag.
````